# pass on json and take result depend on 2 rows - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON in javascript from ajax server responde

I need to pass it and get new json or arrat or something else that will return me the num that the state is "0" it 2 types

for example:

```
id:1 num:1 type:A state:0
id:2 num:1 type:B state:0
```

this is good num!! I need this num because state 0 is in type A an B

but this is not good

```
id:1 num:1 type:A state:0
id:2 num:1 type:B state:1
```

**so for this json my num will be : 1,3**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "num":1,
        "type":"A",
        "state": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "num":1,
        "type":"B",
        "state": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "num":2,
        "type":"A",
        "state": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "num":2,
        "type":"B",
        "state": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "num":3,
        "type":"A",
        "state": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "num":3,
        "type":"B",
        "state": 0
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var aa = [
        { "id": 1, "num": 1, "type": "A", "state": 0 },
        { "id": 2, "num": 1, "type": "B", "state": 0 },
        { "id": 3, "num": 2, "type": "A", "state": 1 },
        { "id": 4, "num": 2, "type": "B", "state": 0 },
        { "id": 5, "num": 3, "type": "A", "state": 0 },
        { "id": 6, "num": 3, "type": "B", "state": 0 }
    ],
    num = {},
    result = [],
    i;

aa.forEach(function (a, i) {
    if (a.state === 0) {
        num[a.num] = num[a.num] || [];
        num[a.num].push(i);
    }
});
for (i in num) {
    if (num[i].length >= 2) {
        result.push(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is return "2"   but i need num :1 , 3, also in console it is return Object {undefined: Array[0]}

Comment: the result is in `result`.